# Different fonts for buffer, minibuffer and modeline

Tags: faces, fonts, frames, minibuffer

I tried `set-frame-font` but it changes the font for not just the buffer, but also minibuffer and modeline.

Is it possible to just change the font for the buffer, but not minibuffer and modeline?

i.e. I want to change the font of the text I'm editing, but not the font of emacs' own interface.

Answer (score 1):

To get this

[image]

do this

```lisp
(require 'subr-x)
(require 'seq)

(require 'face-remap)

(defface default-text
  '((t :family "Comic Sans MS"))
  "Face for regular text."
  :group 'basic-faces)

(custom-set-variables
 '(buffer-face-mode-face 'default-text-face))

(custom-set-faces
 '(default-text-face  ((t (:family "Comic Sans MS"))) t)
 '(org-default ((t (:inherit default-text)))))

(defun buffer-face-mode--turn-on ()
  (when (and (not (minibufferp))
             (thread-last '(text-mode)
                          (seq-some
                           (lambda (it)
                             (derived-mode-p it)))))
    (buffer-face-mode 1)))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-buffer-face-mode
  buffer-face-mode buffer-face-mode--turn-on)

(global-buffer-face-mode 1)
```